# Serializing Special Characters into DB, is there an alternative to base64?

Tags: php, serialization, base64, character, deserialization

I'm storing user input into a serialized array in my database.

Later, I deserialize this string into an array to get back my original data.

All works and is fine, but when the user enters really weird characters like these for example 
(*notice how I'm not talking about characters like ëęæoõö*):

> ⌹ ⌺ ⌻ ⌼ ⍯ ⍰ ⌽ ⌾ ⌿ ⍀ ⍁ ⍂ ⍉ ⍊ 
>  [more here...](http://www.copypastecharacter.com/all-characters)

Then my whole site completely messes up... Now I read someone say to base64_encode into database and base64_decode out of the database, but I was wondering if there was any alternative to this?

Thanks in advance,

Nathan

Comment: You don't need `base64_encode` if you set up your database, your database connection, your php code AND your html encoding correctly. 
In case you're using MySQL, read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279#279279).

Comment: Thanks! That's great. It's working now :-)